# AS3+PHP+MySQL : home-made online chat not always reactive

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I coded some kind of online chat system with a Flash (AS3) client that sends and retrieves data from a PHP script that communicates with a MySQL database.

It works well, except for the fact that **occasionally, my client doesn't get one of the new chat lines** even though they are correctly registered in the database.

Here is the basic logic behind it : every user has an entry in the database, and each of those entries has a **lastChatCheck** BigInt(16) variable.
When a user types and sends a chat line, the client sends it to a PHP script, where it is stored in the database, along with the **date** it was stored at (it is also a BigInt(16) ).
The flash client checks every 250 milliseconds through a getter PHP script for every chat line where (**line's date>user's lastChatCheck**), then sets the user's **lastChatCheck** to the last retrieved line's **date**. (Please tell me if this is confusing or poorly explained.)

I am positive that the code I wrote to *send* a new line is correct, as everything I send gets correctly stored in the database.

**The (simplified) PHP code for getting the chat lines is like so :**

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT lastChatCheck FROM players WHERE id='.$id);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$lastChatCheck=$row['lastChatCheck'];
}

$output='';

$chatDate=0;

$result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM chat WHERE date>'.$lastChatCheck);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$chatSayer=$row['sayer'];
$chatText=$row['text'];
$chatDate=$row['date'];
$result2=mysql_query('SELECT name FROM players WHERE id='.$chatSayer);
while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
$output.=$row2['name'].' : '.$row['text'].'<br>';
//(in reality, $output is formatted as an XML object)
}

}


if ($chatDate!=0) mysql_query('UPDATE players SET lastChatCheck='.$chatDate.' WHERE id='.$id);
```

Is there any logical reason why this would skip some of the recent chat lines ? Is there any way I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I check for chats at the same time as one gets posted, meaning that the bigint is the same for the check time and the posting, then it's possible that a chat message could get added for the "current time" *after* you have fetched the chats for that time.  In other words, you could have this sequence:

TIME 0: Client A fetches chats.  Sets lastChatCheck = 0.

TIME 1: Client A fetches chats > 0.  Sets lastChatCheck = 1.  Client B posts chat, time 1.

TIME 2: Client A fetches chats > 1.  Does not see client B post.

Instead of using a BigInt, why not use TIMESTAMP?

Also, in your PHP code, consider doing a JOIN so you don't have to do a separate MYSQL call for every chat line.